# Assistance with a regular expression mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a database column with data that looks like  **file_name|||file_id|||field_id**  I would like to run a query to replace the data with just the **file_id**.

So, my query, in essence needs to parse out the file_id between the pipes, and then update the field to replace the full string with just the file id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find rows in the old format with

```
WHERE mycol LIKE '%|||%|||%';
```

To extract the middle field you could use

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycol, '|||', -2)
```

which would return 'fileid|||fieldid', and then

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycol, '|||', -2), '|||', 1)
```

which would return 'fileid'.

So:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycol = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycol, '|||', -2), '|||', 1) WHERE mycol LIKE '%|||%|||%';
```

But first I'd check with

```
SELECT 
    mycol AS beforethecure,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycol, '|||', -2), '|||', 1) AS afterthecure
FROM mytable
WHERE mycol LIKE '%|||%|||%';
```

just in case. And maybe a SELECT on the results of 'after' to see whether they conform to the syntax for fileid.

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( SUBSTRING_INDEX('file_name|||file_id|||field_id','|||', 2), 
                 LOCATE('|',  'file_name|||file_id|||field_id' ) + 3  )
```